# Project starting in embedded Tomcat, but doesn't work in full Tomcat

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have small SpringBoot project with few RESTful-services which I made for studying Spring and REST technology. If I run it through spring-boot:run it working properly on localhost:8080/ + what I wrote in @RequestMapping in Controller. In example, on localhost:8080/restapp/test/{id} :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "http ://localhost:8080/restapps-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/restapp/test/{id}",
      method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getWelcome(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) {
    return "Welcome to jax-rs " + id;
}
```

While deploying in full Tomcat, it started on localhost:8080/project_version it opened index.html (whitch I added for testing while created project) and i haven't access to my services. I trying:

localhost:8080/project_version/restapp/test/{id}

localhost:8080/project_version/test/{id}

localhost:8080/project_version/project_name/restapp/test/{id}

but have only 404 error.

Application.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
@RestController
public class Controller extends ApplicationConfig {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(Controller.class);
        return s;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "http ://localhost:8080/restapps-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/restapp/test/{id}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getWelcome(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) {
        return "Welcome to jax-rs " + id;
    }
}
```

ApplicationConfig - empty class, which extends Application.

Thanx for all advises/answers.

Comment: One more thing - it seems like Application.java doesn't start at all, because lines `Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Application.class.getName());
        log.info("///////// Application started successfully, ////////");` don't change anything in Tomcat log files. There only information about deploying project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by extending Application from SpringBootServletInitializer.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller mapping is NOT correct because Controller **`@RequestMapping` `value` should be only the relative path**, not the absolute path, so it needs to be changed as shown below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/test")
public class Controller extends ApplicationConfig {

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getWelcome(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) {
        return "Welcome to jax-rs " + id;
    }
}
```

You should be able to access your Controller method using the below url (for resource id 1):

```
http ://localhost:8080/restapps-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test/1
```

Comment: I know, in original it was like this `@RestController @RequestMapping(value = "/restapp") public class Controller extends ApplicationConfig { ... @RequestMapping(value = "/test/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET) public String getWelcome(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) { return "Welcome to jax-rs " + id; } }`
Then I was trying to make it work, so change path in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add @SpringBootApplication or @EnableWebMvc in Application class.
Then see **javaguy**'s answer.

Comment: But @ SpringBootApplication is equal to using @ Configuration, @ EnableAutoConfiguration and @ ComponentScan, which I already have.
And  @ EnableWebMvc can be used only in Configuration class, if needed.